# How to display the search results of all possible search queries on a single page?

Tags: javascript, html

> I want that on clicking "Find a Camp" link all the camps that means camps of all states,all genders,all sports, and all age range must be
>   displayed and the url should be
>   "http://gogliderhosting.com/spocamp.com/find-a-camp/" in the browser.

```
<li ><a href="http://gogliderhosting.com/spocamp.com/find-a-camp/" >Find A Camp</a></li>
```

> Moreover I have code for search query which will return camp only for
>   a specific sport,state,gender and age range which is as follows.Can
>   you modify the function so that my above mentioned requirements are
>   fulfilled.Further,how would I access this function from "Find a Camp"
>   link as it is redirecting me to
>   "http://gogliderhosting.com/spocamp.com/find-a-camp/".Thanx for ur
>   help..

```
<script>

        function SearchNow() {
            search = jQuery('input[name="ofsearch"]').val();
            v1 = jQuery('#ofait-dir-item-sport option:selected').text().toLowerCase();
            v2 = jQuery('#ofait-dir-item-Gender option:selected').text().toLowerCase();
            v3 = jQuery('#ofait-dir-item-state option:selected').text().toLowerCase();
            v4 = jQuery('#ofait-dir-item-Age option:selected').text().toLowerCase();
            if(search == '' && v1 == 'sport' && v2 == 'gender' && v3 == 'state' && v4 == 'age range') { 
                window.location = "http://gogliderhosting.com/spocamp.com/?s=%20";
            } else {
                q = '';

                if(v1 != 'sport') {
                    q = q + "&ait-dir-item-sport="+v1 ;
                } 

                if(v2 != 'gender') {
                    q = q + "&ait-dir-item-Gender="+v2;
                } 

                if(v3 != 'state') {
                    q = q + "&ait-dir-item-state="+v3;
                } 

                if(v4 != 'age range') {
                    q = q + "&ait-dir-item-Age="+v4;
                } 

                window.location = "http://gogliderhosting.com/spocamp.com/?s=%20"+q;
            }
        }


</script>
```

Comment: You may have to give an example, your question is not very clear.

Comment: Check the site "http://gogliderhosting.com/spocamp.com/" and on the front page from the drop down meus select state,sport,gender,and age group and then select search button.You will get the result of camps for a specific state,specific gender,specific sport and so on.But I want the list of camps for all states, all genders, all sports and so on .that's it..

Comment: Create a Database View of the kind of output you want. Use the View to gather all the columns in the form you will like them displayed.  Then you will send only one JQuery call to query that view. You will use AND/OR to now join the filter conditions.

Comment: what about keeping it empty? http://gogliderhosting.com/spocamp.com/?s=